# LINQ to Data Set - nulls

Tags: c#, linq

I have query as below:

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(jobTitle))
        {
            query = from users in query
                    where users.Field<string>("job_title").ToUpper().Contains(jobTitle.ToUpper())
                    select users;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(officerTitle))
        {
            query = from users in query
                    where users.Field<string>("officer_title") != null
                    where users.Field<string>("officer_title").ToUpper().Contains(officerTitle.ToUpper())                        
                    select users;
        }
```

When I'm using second query without

```
where users.Field<string>("officer_title") != null
```

it returns an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I did check database and I found that in both cases `job_title` and `officer_tittle` contain `NULL`. I am wondering why in first query that error didn't occur.

Comment: because you can not call ToUpper() on null

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon but it works in first query without any issues.

Comment: Perhaps all people have a job_title, but not all have officer_titles?

Comment: @BugFinder I checked directly in the database and I found some nulls in job_title column.

Comment: Im guessing they didnt match the jobtitle you searched on then.. you could probably get round this issue with c# 6 which allows you to do a lot of null checking inline

Comment: @BugFinder What do you mean by "they didnt match the jobtitle you searched on " ?

Comment: Not database, check in tour fetched IQueryable type query, whether there's a users.Field<string>("job_title") null, i assume No, but following users.Field<string>("officer_title") is Null and that is causing the issue